# When testing a class library with an NUnit project, where should I put app.config?

Tags: nunit

I'm testing a class library with a separate Nunit test project, which is another class library.
The unit tests are run by resharper, but the problem is, the class library is expecting to get configuration values from app.config.

When NUnit project is a class library, then there is no place to put app.config so that the class library can access the values in it.

If the NUnit project was an executable, it'd host the app.config, but that is not what is suggested according to questions and answers on SO

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are talking about. You just add app.config to your test project. It works. I do it (when I need values from config) with and without resharper.

This may also help you - http://nunit.net/blogs/?p=9